# Send event-related emails in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to send email to user when some event occurs, I had searched on internet and I couldn't find how to do it.
Can anyone show me right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Javamail library for sending email to user with the help of sendgrid.net email server.

Then I just implemented at what event I wanted to send email to the users.
Tips: Use latest version of Javamail and don't forget to turn on Internet Permission in Manifest file

```
   private fun sendMail(etEmail: EditText, etSubject: EditText, etMessage: EditText) {



        // Set up the mail server
        val host = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
        val props = Properties().apply {
            put("mail.smtp.auth", "true")
            put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true")
            put("mail.smtp.host", host)
            put("mail.smtp.port", "465")
        }

        // Set up authentication
        val session = Session.getInstance(props, object : Authenticator() {
            override fun getPasswordAuthentication() =
                PasswordAuthentication("apikey","yourpaswordxyzfromsendgridaccount")
        })

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object
            val message = MimeMessage(session).apply {
                setFrom(InternetAddress("abc@xyz"))
                addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress(etEmail.text.toString()))
                subject = etSubject.text.toString()
                setText(etMessage.text.toString())
            }

            // Send the message
            thread(start = true) {
                Transport.send(message)
                println("Email sent successfully.")

                println("running from thread(): ${Thread.currentThread()}")
            }
            Toast.makeText(this,"Mail sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()



        } catch (e: MessagingException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }


}
```